# Merging 2 fields into 1 from different table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

How do I combine into 1 column the 2 fields from different table. I have `dbo.Desktop_Info` with the field of `desktop_info_id` & `dbo.Laptops_info` with the field of `laptop_info_id`. I want in my view to combine the two fields into 1 including the data. Now, how will I do this? Can you provide me the codes on how to do it?

dbo.Desktop_Info

```
desktop_info_id  dt_serial_no
------------------------------
1                9PP7D2S
2                9PP7D2S1
```

dbo.laptop_info

```
laptop_info_id  lp_serial_no
------------------------------
1                9PP7D2S2
2                9PP7D2S3
```

Expected result:

```
vw_id   type        trans_id    Serial_No
-----------------------------------------------
1       Desktop       1          9PP7D2S
2       Desktop       2          9PP7D2S1
3       Laptop        1          9PP7D2S2
4       Laptop        2          9PP7D2S3
```

Comment: Yes we can. But first, kindly provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Sure, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `UNION ALL` to combine the data and `ROW_NUMBER` to assign `vw_id`:

```
SELECT
    vw_id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
    *
FROM(
    SELECT 
        type = 'Desktop',
        trans_id = desktop_info_id,
        Serial_No = dt_serial_no
    FROM desktop_info
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        type = 'Laptop',
        trans_id = laptop_info_id, 
        Seral_No = lp_serial_no
    FROM laptop_info
)AS t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UNION ALL`. Something like this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY type,trans_id) as vw_id,type,trans_id,dt_serial_no 
FROM (
SELECT  'Desktop' as type,desktop_info_id as trans_id,  dt_serial_no as dt_serial_no
FROM dbo.Desktop_Info
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Laptop' as type,laptop_info_id as trans_id,  lp_serial_no as dt_serial_no
FROM dbo.laptop_info
)T
```

Comment: What the use of 'T' in the statement?

Comment: its the alias of the table from the inner query. try the updated code